# Pentaho CDE Line Chart Padding

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, charts, pentaho, dashboard, pentaho-cde

I'd like to remove the gap between the start of my line, and the Y-axis, is there a variable that'll let me do that?

[image]

I've messed around with every padding, and margin variable that I could find, but nothing has changed. Is there an extension point I'm missing? I'm hoping to make my chart look more like this:
[image]

Comment: Here you have only one option that is please decrease the height of the chart.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion Venkatesh, but even after I halved the height of the chart, the gap is still present.

Comment: Can you attach your chart image please.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/WVq7k.png